# Right vector t but wrong final answer

Tags: r

```
x <- c(1,2,3)
C <- 2
t <- numeric(length(10))

for(i in 0:9){
  t <- c((min(x)+ i*C))
  print(t[i])
}
```

I tried to create vector `t` of size 10, however the final answer is not correct.

Comment: Indexing in R starts at 1, not at 0.

Comment: Do you want `t <- min(x) + (0:9)*C`?

Comment: why not directly `t = min(x) + 0:9*C` ?

Comment: t is a base-function in R, it's not good practice to name your variables the same as functions.

Comment: I already solve and I fix the problem

Comment: t<- c((min(x)+ (0:(p-1))*C))

Comment: truncated.polynomial<-function(x,t,r){
  for ( i in 1: length(x))
    if (x[i]>t[i]){
      print((x[i]-t[i])**r)
    }
  
}

Answer (score 1):

The comment above from @Pascal is correct and you also need to append the new value to t. This just creates a new vector t each time with one value.

One last point, t is a built-in function in R so you shouldn't use it as a variable name. I've changed it to t0 below.

```
x<-c(1,2,3)

C<-2

t0 <- numeric(length(10))

for (i in 1:10){
    t0 <- c(t0, (min(x)+ (i-1)*C))
    print(t0[i])
}

print(t0)
```